# Ember.js: ensure parent is loaded

Tags: ember.js

This might be a simple question, but I can't seem to find any current (RC1) example on how to achive this.

So let's say I've got the following two routes:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});

App.PostCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

How do I ensure that the controller of the PostRoute is loaded when I access the PostComment route directly. I.e. by calling #/post/comment directly from the browser?

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but there is an entire Discourse.org forum for ember.js should you want to use it in the future: http://discuss.emberjs.com/

Comment: are you encountering a problem where the parent is not loaded?

Comment: yes. so you are saying that It should be loaded by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the PostRoute `model` hook to return a promise.  If you are using ember-data, this is done automatically for you.

The router checks, and if the object returned by the `model` hook implements the `then` function (which means it's a promise), it will transition the router into a `loading` state until the promise is resolved (which means the data was fetched).  Then it will continue to the `PostCommentRoute`.

Comment: my problem is that, I'm not using Ember.Data (we started our project at a time when ember.data was not ready). So this means we have our own way of geting and settng the controller data. I'm not returning a promise right now, which seems to be the problem.. Any pointers where I can get a better understanding of how to make that promise?